# List all objects that implements Node interface

Tags: javascript, dom

I have some idea that `HTMLElement`,`DocumentType` and `Attr` objects implement Node interface.

Can i retrieve a complete list of DOM objects who implements Node interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes/No.

You should just read the specs

- [DOM4](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/)
- [HTML](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/)

Comment: thanks, does window.document also implements Node interface? DOM4 Says It is used by all nodes (Document, DocumentFragment, DocumentType, Element, Text, ProcessingInstruction, and Comment).

Comment: @Praveen `document instanceof Node`

Comment: @Raynos—you are assuming the host implements ECMAScript inheritance for host objects. You shouldn't. Host objects implementing the Node interface don't have to be instances of Node (or anything) and aren't in at least one popular browser. They just have to have the appropriate behaviour. Feeding a host object to the `instanceof` operator could do anything, including throw an error. If your intention was to reference a standard, you should link to DOM 3 since DOM 4 isn't a standard, it's a working draft.

Comment: any webidl compliant browser would print true. and no u, dom3 is old. reference the latest editor draft of dom4